# TableView HeaderSections hide buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have been trying to fix an issue that I encountered with a tableviewcontroller.

The sections within the tableviewcontroller are views:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let sectionLabel = UILabel()
    sectionLabel.text = Catalog.sharedInstance.allSections[section - 1].name.localized(lang: defaults.string(forKey: "language")!)
    sectionLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Centabel Book", size: 25)
    sectionLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    sectionLabel.clipsToBounds = true

    return sectionLabel

}
```

If I try to add a button programatically to put it over the tableview

```
    let actionButton = JJFloatingActionButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configuration of the Floating Action Button
    actionButton.buttonColor = .red
    actionButton.addItem { item in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSettings", sender: nil)
    }
    actionButton.display(inViewController: self)
    actionButton.clipsToBounds = true
    // This doesn't work. It is to bring the button to the front. Now it is hidden by the sections.
    view.bringSubviewToFront(actionButton)

    // Checks if the language setting is nil, which means it is the first time you run the application. If then... selects English as default.
    if defaults.string(forKey: "language") == nil {

        defaults.set("en", forKey: "language")

    }

}
```

... I don't know why but the viewForHeaderInSection hides the button. You can check it in the picture below:

[floating button hided by the headersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZWwA.png)

I tried to use the method:

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(actionButton)
```

and also:

```
actionbutton.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(actionButton)
```

But none of this brings the button to the front.

I am using a floating action button from github called JJFloatingActionButton. But I tried to add a simple UIButton and I got the same error. This is the code that also gave me the same error inside viewDidLoad:

```
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 1000, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Again the same error. You can check the picture:

[adding a simple UIButton happens the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydbeh.png)

May be you can help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you trying to add the button ? in the tableview section or in the view over the tableview?

Comment: I am trying to put it over the tableview. It is floating over the tableviewcontroller.

Comment: can you share some of the code where you add the button

Comment: I added more code.

Comment: You can try to set actionButton.layer.zPosition higher than zPosition of your tableView, by default it's 0. So try to set actionButton.layer.zPosition = 1

Comment: Perfect Nazar Lisovyi!!!!! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a regular `UIViewController` (not `UITableViewController`) and add the `UITableView` by hand.

Like that you would have better control over the view hierarchy.